# Creating Spiral program using individual characters

Tags: c++

Im having a hard time doing this assignment. We need to recreate these spirals in C++. The function should take in an input known as "Order" and output a spiral with "Order" lines on each side of the spiral so they look as follows:

order 1)

```
+++
  +
+ +
+++
```

order 2)

```
+++++++
      +
+++++ +
+   + +
+ + + +
+ +++ +
+     +
+++++++
```

We are not allowed to use arrays and are expected to calculate each line on the fly and then cout the line. I am asking for some ideas to get me going. Currently I know that Height (of the spiral) = 4*order, and width (of spiral) = 3*order + order-1.

What im looking for is advice on how to calculate each line on the fly so that I can print out the spiral from top-to-bottom. If you have any questions let me know so I can clear it up. Thanks.

Comment: If you had a function that would draw the spiral for order *n*, could you write a function that would draw the spiral for order *n + 1*?

Answer (score 0):

Write the program first using an array. Then just remove the array. You don't actually need it since you'll never read from it (except for final output). Basically, just repeat the code that fills the array for each character, except instead of actually filling an array, just note whether or not you ever filled that particular character. If so, output a `+`. If not, output a space.